# A formal word for "to go wrong"

Tags: word-request

I would like to use a verb  or an adjective similar to " to go wrong" as in the following example but I could not find.

> A myriad of scientists endeavored and even some of them sacrificed their lives due
>   to/through  accidents that happened during ? experiments that had gone wrong.

Comment: You can envisage a scientist such as Marie Curie who passed away due to being exposed X-rays so I do not want to use the word failed for these kind of experiments. They just did not know everything.

Comment: A related word is [**misadventure**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/death-by-misadventure), although that is a noun.

Comment: @stangdon how about this one : "...sacrificed their lives due to a series of misadventures involving / concerning experiments they conducted"

Comment: How about **experiments with unexpected consequences**?

Comment: @Mrt - I think "sacrificed their lives due to misadventures involving experiments" would be a good phrasing.  We usually say that someone died due to misadventure, so saying that they died from a series of misadventures sounds a little odd.  *involving* is better than *concerning*, because *concerning* makes it sound like the misadventures were about the experiments.

Answer (score 1):

A very good point is mentioned by Mrt in the comment. Marie Curie sacrificed her life to gift us the science of X-rays that would later save lives of millions. So, in such cases, telling it the experiments that went *wrong* or *were failed* is not good.

Now, if the experiments have gone wrong not just for the scientists but also for the rest of the world, as we see *movies,* they are popularly known as *bizarre experiments.*  A wise man's advice is: [Bizarre experiments should never be repeated.](http://mentalfloss.com/article/26483/4-bizarre-experiments-should-never-be-repeated)

But in your case, you want to tell that many lost their lives because experiments went in some other directions, it's safe to use a little *phrase* rather than going for a *single word* that may make it ambiguous.

Surprisingly, you **wrote** that answer in your question only!

> A myriad of scientists endeavored and even some of them sacrificed their lives due to/through accidents that happened during ***experiments that had gone wrong*** [sic].

It's up to you to use any *adjective*; for instance, [*shocking experiments that went wrong.*](https://www.therichest.com/rich-list/most-shocking/10-shocking-psychological-experiments-gone-wrong/)